# using Visual studio on a vm on Mac with Git

Tags: macos, git, visual-studio, virtual-machine

I've just switched over to using a mac, (hooray!) ... But I'm still a Dot.Net developer.. so running vmfusion, and that seem to work pretty well.

I'm using git for source control, so I have git installed on the mac and on the virtual machine, I currently do all my source control form the pc, But, should I be sharing a folder and doing source control form the mac? Git seems faster on the mac, (only a bit it's pretty fast anyway),

I'm currently working on my own, if i started working in a team would this have implication sharing source with people on pc's?

The current set up works well, should I leave it alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience (with Parallels, but likely to carry over to vmfusion), even if source control is faster on the native mac, working with a native mac folder inside the VM is much slower than working with regular VM files. I would stick with what you're doing.

As for your second question, this should not affect source sharing.

Comment: +1. It's also worth being aware of line-endings issues. I've known of a couple of people who've got themselves into a bit of a mess by cloning a repo to their mac and editing the files and committing in windows.